# Display on hover, but just on hovered item

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to make this work:

**HTML:**

```
<div>    
   <p> Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
<div>
   <p> Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
<div>
   <p> Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div
{
  p
  {
    display:none;
  }
}

div:hover
{
   p
   {
     display:block;
    }
}
```

**Function:**
When I hover on a div I need to see a paragraph in it. But problem is, when I hover one div, text is visible in all divs at the same time. Is there any way to have visible paragraph only on a hovered div?

**Preferred option:** 
No JavaScript or JQuery. Only CSS.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use any css preprocessor?

Comment: Yes. Using LESS in this particular example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
div p{
  display:none;
}

div:hover p{
   display:block;
}
```

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Leqaumq0/)

Comment: This is the solutions I would go for:)

Answer (score 3):

Your css selection is not correct, please check the below code. Also div should have other content or (width and height) property, else the div will not be visible. So in this example I've added "less text" to solve that.

```css
div p {
  display:none;
}

div:hover p {
   display:block;
}
```

```html
<div>   less text
   <p> Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
<div>   less text
   <p> Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
<div>   less text
   <p> Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Unfortunatelly tR4xX was first with this one.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using less you can use the below rule.

```
div
{
  p{
     display:none;
   }

  &:hover p
   {
      display:block;
   }
}
```

Comment: This might actually solve my problem too. I had  &:hover p{display:block;} outside of the div brackets not inside. Thanks.